# Is there any drugstore that is open 24 hours in Bangkok?

Tags: health, thailand, shopping, bangkok, nightlife

Is there any drugstore that is open 24 hours in Bangkok?

I thought there would be plenty but I haven't been able yet to found any.

- Searching for [drugstores open 24 hours in Bangkok in Google Maps](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=lcl&sxsrf=ALeKk01PCOFlL0HyA0zGhMmWU8iiJw8_zw%3A1593296340918&ei=1MX3Xv3RN7SF4-EPucSF-Ac&q=pharmacy&oq=pharmacy+&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39k1j0l3j0i20i263k1j0l5.7799.7799.0.7998.1.1.0.0.0.0.103.103.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.103....0.WhFGcx3DBXg&rlfi=hd:;si:&tbs=lrf:!1m4!1u16!2m2!16m1!1e1!1m4!1u16!2m2!16m1!1e2!1m4!1u3!2m2!3m1!1e1!2m1!1e16!2m4!1e3!5m2!3m1!1e2!3sIAE,lf:1,lf_ui:3&rlst=f&fll=13.73945556395674,100.56141979847327&fspn=0.017321096281182946,0.0308990478515625&fz=16&sll=13.73945556395674,100.56141979847327&sspn=0.017321096281182946,0.0308990478515625&sz=16#rlfi=hd:;si:6373729098110687633,l,CghwaGFybWFjeVoUCghwaGFybWFjeSIIcGhhcm1hY3k;mv:%5B%5B13.801029348577424,100.90036518726721%5D,%5B13.523801200103266,100.40598042164221%5D%5D), I see a few drugstores listed but typically with no or very few reviews: I called a few of them but nobody reply, so I doubt these 24 open hours shown on Google are accurate.
- [Samitivej Sukhumvit Hospital](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Samitivej+Sukhumvit+Hospital/@13.7333683,100.5657076,16z/data=!4m8!1m2!2m1!1sSamitivej+Hospital!3m4!1s0x30e29e5511e0a255:0xa9f4f72fa8144b75!8m2!3d13.7348727!4d100.5765805) has a [pharmacy that is open 24 hours](https://www.samitivejhospitals.com/patients-outside-thailand/after-care/pharmacy/), but it requires prescriptions from Samitivej Sukhumvit Hospital physicians (I called them to confirm +6620222222; the interlocutor I had also wasn't aware of any drugstore that is open 24 hours in Bangkok)
- https://www.pharmaciesworldwide.com/24-hours-pharmacies-in-thailand/s-pharmacies-in-bangkok/ was unhelpful (nonexistent drugstores / can't find them on Google Maps / nobody answer the phone).

If no drugstore is open 24 hours, then I'd be interest is a set of drugstores whose union of opening times is 24 hours. But I can't find anything open late at night (covering ~midnight to 7am).

Comment: Since Thailand does have shops which stock similar ranges of stuff as American drugstores, are you looking for one of those specifically, or are you after medicinal stuff like from a pharmacy? I'm sure 24-hour pharmacies are more common than 24-hour drugstores but 7-11 has a pretty similar range to a drugstore anyway. So I guess it depends what you're looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Bangkok, 7-Eleven are open 24 hrs and inside there is usually a pharmacy section where you can buy over the counter medication.
However, you shouldn't call them drugstore as people may misperceive that you are looking for drugs lol.

Typically hospital pharmacies are quite a bit more expensive but may legally sell some drugs with restricted access. Some street pharmacies will sell those illegally but if they are willing to break the law on that, how do you know they are not selling equally illegal fake medicine?

On the streets you will see people selling viagra, valium, etc but be careful and use good judgement. Don't buy or do drugs in discotheques. It's not worth it if you get caught.

Comment: Thanks for the information and the terminology warning :)

Comment: No worries mate. Any time.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting answer from [Vovicon](https://www.reddit.com/user/Vovicon) on https://redd.it/hh3hij, pointing out one can look at street view/pictures to try to spot a 24 hour open sign (and hope that the opening hours are still accurate: calling the business, if their phone number is disclosed somewhere, might be a good idea to confirm):

> [...] businesses here are still very bad at updating their listings on Google maps (on more generally online). [...]There's a franchise called"Bangkok Drugstores" which has many branches and seem to maintain their Google listings better. You can see for example this one is listed as 24h and just checking street view/pictures you can see it says "24h" on their main signage: https://maps.app.goo.gl/E7HrPGsGom4BR58T7

We can indeed see a 24 red sign on the entrance door:

[image]

Another example of a drugstore that is open 24 hours in Bangkok?: [JC Pharma](https://g.page/Drugstore24hrs?share):

[image]

It'd still be more convenient to have a centralized, up-to-date list of drugstores with their business hours/days instead of having to manually spot "24" on the images (or Google or others could help by deploying some text detection algorithms to automatically extract business hours).